# "Dotnet ef migrations add" not creating the migration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I am trying to update my database but the migration isn't actually created, if I name the old migrations folder it changes the snapshot but doesn't create the actual migrations,
if I name another folder nothing get created.
I am still in early development (where dropping databases is perfectly acceptable) so I tried to squash the whole thing.

new try (I am in the same project as my DbContext)

```
dotnet ef migrations add Init -o \Migrations\Init -s ..\<StartupLocation>
```

Creates a folder, creates a snapshot, but doesn't create the actual migration.

```
dotnet ef migrations list -s ..\<StartupLocation>
```

Finds nothing

```
dotnet ef database update -s ..\<StartupLocation>
```

Creates an empty database...

I'm using SQLite...

I tried searching for the issue but I come across other problems, any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Cleaning the solution does not resolve the issue

DbContext

```
public EcomContext( DbContextOptions<EcomContext> options ) : base( options )
{}
//Fix for nullable reference types
public DbSet<SomeClass> SomeClass => Set<SomeClass>();
//Just a string wrapper with int id and string
public DbSet<StringWrapper> StringWrapperers => Set<StringWrapper>();

protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly( 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() );
    base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
}
```

SomeClass

```
public class SomeClass
    {
    public SomeClass( string firstNonNullableValue, string secondNonNullableValue, string thirdNonNullableValue )
    {
        FirstNonNullableValue = firstNonNullableValue;
        SecondNonNullableValue = secondNonNullableValue;
        ThirdNonNullableValue = thirdNonNullableValue ;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstNonNullableValue{ get; set; }

    public string SecondNonNullableValue{ get; set; }

    public string ThirdNonNullableValue{ get; set; }

    public string? JustAString { get; set; }
//RangedValue is just a owned type with 2 ints
    public RangedValue? Value { get; set; }
    public RangedValue? Value2 { get; set; }
    public SomeEnum? SomeEnum{ get; set; }
    public IList<StringWrapper>? StringWrappers { get; set; }

    public string? SomeString { get; set; }
    public string? SomeString2 { get; set; }
}
```

Edited: Including build logs

Migration

```
PS D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data> dotnet ef migrations add Tags -s ..\Ecom.API\ -o /migrations/Tags -v
Using project 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\Ecom.Data.csproj'.
Using startup project '..\Ecom.API\Ecom.API.csproj'.
Writing 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\obj\Ecom.Data.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\Supremus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDD49.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\Ecom.Data.csproj"
Writing '..\Ecom.API\obj\Ecom.API.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\Supremus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDFFA.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo ..\Ecom.API\Ecom.API.csproj
Build started...
dotnet build ..\Ecom.API\Ecom.API.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.01
Build succeeded.
dotnet exec --depsfile "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0\Ecom.API.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\Supremus\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0\Ecom.API.runtimeconfig.json" C:\Users\Supremus\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\5.0.7\dotnet-ef\5.0.7\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add Tags -o /migrations/Tags --assembly "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0\Ecom.Data.dll" --startup-assembly "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0\Ecom.API.dll" --project-dir "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\\" --language C# --working-dir "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data" --verbose --root-namespace Ecom.Data
Using assembly 'Ecom.Data'.
Using startup assembly 'Ecom.API'.
Using application base 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0'.
Using working directory 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API'.
Using root namespace 'Ecom.Data'.
Using project directory 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\'.
Remaining arguments: .
The Entity Framework tools version '5.0.7' is older than that of the runtime '5.0.9'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'Ecom.API'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Found DbContext 'EcomContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'EcomContext'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'Ecom.API'...
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'Ecom.Data'...
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'Ecom.API'...
No design-time services were found.
Reusing namespace of type 'Init'.
An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy.
Writing migration to 'D:\migrations\Tags\20210823160452_Tags.cs'.
Writing model snapshot to 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\Migrations\Product\EcomContextModelSnapshot.cs'.
```

update

```
PS D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data> dotnet ef database update -s ..\Ecom.API\ -v
Using project 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\Ecom.Data.csproj'.
Using startup project '..\Ecom.API\Ecom.API.csproj'.
Writing 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\obj\Ecom.Data.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\Supremus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpFE02.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\Ecom.Data.csproj"
Writing '..\Ecom.API\obj\Ecom.API.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\Supremus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC2.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo ..\Ecom.API\Ecom.API.csproj
Build started...
dotnet build ..\Ecom.API\Ecom.API.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.15
Build succeeded.
dotnet exec --depsfile "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0\Ecom.API.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\Supremus\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0\Ecom.API.runtimeconfig.json" C:\Users\Supremus\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\5.0.7\dotnet-ef\5.0.7\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll database update --assembly "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0\Ecom.Data.dll" --startup-assembly "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0\Ecom.API.dll" --project-dir "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\\" --language C# --working-dir "D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data" --verbose --root-namespace Ecom.Data
Using assembly 'Ecom.Data'.
Using startup assembly 'Ecom.API'.
Using application base 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API\bin\Debug\net5.0'.
Using working directory 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.API'.
Using root namespace 'Ecom.Data'.
Using project directory 'D:\Software\Visual Studio\Projects\Ecom\Ecom.Data\'.
Remaining arguments: .
The Entity Framework tools version '5.0.7' is older than that of the runtime '5.0.9'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'Ecom.API'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Found DbContext 'EcomContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'EcomContext'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'Ecom.API'...
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'Ecom.Data'...
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'Ecom.API'...
No design-time services were found.
Done.
```

Comment: Are you sure your db is actually different from your classes?  Also please post your dbcontext and one or two of your entity classes.

Comment: can you run the ef command with verbose flag and post the log here. example `dotnet ef database update -s ..\<StartupLocation> --verbose`

Comment: @Sam Sure thing, adde d slightly scrubbed code into the original post

Comment: @FirdausKamaruddin Included above

Comment: Hi @BananaSupreme, the log said `The Entity Framework tools version '5.0.7' is older than that of the runtime '5.0.9'.`. I think you need firstly update the ef tool by using: `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef`.

Comment: @Rena Done, did not fix the problem, but thanks I was wondering how to get rid of that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dotnet ef migrations add Init -o \Migrations\Init -s ..\<StartupLocation>
```

It's missing a dot so it's outputting to an absolute path rather a relative path...
Should be

```
dotnet ef migrations add Init -o .\Migrations\Init -s ..\<StartupLocation>
```

note the dot in the output folder...